# Custom layout aswell as Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going to be re-designing a website that currently uses Bootstrap.

I'm more of a fan of building my own layouts however as this site already uses Bootstrap, I'm unsure how to go about the re-design.

I've never used Bootstrap before (I know how it works from looking at the documentation and videos) but is it possible for me to have parts of a webpage use Bootstrap and other parts not?

For example, say there are 5 sections on a home page. The first section is a full screen hero etc.. then sections 3 and 5 break the grid. Could I use Bootstrap only for sections 2 and 4 but then do my own layout for sections 1, 3 and 5? I'm just curious as to whether or not it would cause problems doing this?

Another example is that we would want something like this on the site: https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html

I assume the best way to implement that would be outside of Bootstrap? So, this would be a section on a page where I don't use it?

I know we could scrap Bootstrap but not all pages on the site are being re-designed, so Bootstrap is already going to be in use. I'm trying to make parts of the site more interactive and "different", so using Bootstrap would be good for basic layout but I don't want to be fighting with it to achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can, Bootstrap are composed just by classes declaration and tags, sometimes you'll need to override some css to make your own style elements but you can do all what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

you have two way to building your own layout

1. Overwrite the `css` of `bootstap`, create new css file and write your won `styles` into it and load embed it after `bootstrap.min.css` in you code.
2. Avoid use of `bootstrap class`, because bootstrap is working on `classes` so 
   avoid to use of bootstrap class.

Comment: Thanks. I won't want to override the Bootstrap css as it's already in use throughout the site. I guess I will just use my own css and avoid any classes within Bootstrap when I don't want to use it.